# Github: enforce source branch in a pull request

Tags: git, github

I am trying to enforce a 'branch flow' in git(hub):

1. Feature branches can be merged (via a PR) into the branch `acceptance`, which will then be deployed in the acceptance environment.
2. Updates to `main` (deployed in prod) must come from a PR (easy to enforce) but **only** from a branch named `acceptance`.

This is this 2nd rule which I do not manage to sort out.

Is there a way?

Comment: You could setup a custom validation rule for completing PR's into `main` that checks the source branch.

Comment: Custom rule, as in a webhook, or something provided by GitHub? I could not find any reference about custom rules.

Comment: I honestly have never done it, but I think it's possible to roll your own checks that do pretty much anything you can think of, perhaps even outside of GitHub. But, you may also be able to take advantage of [require status checks to pass before merging](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule). I think the idea is that the commits must first pass a specified status check, which might be as simple as "auto pass all commits on `acceptance` branch".

Comment: ...cont. Once a commit has landed on `acceptance` it would then be eligible to be merged into `main`. (If I understand how that works; I've never used it though.) This isn't *exactly* the same as you can only merge `acceptance` into `main`, but it would enable you to only merge commits into `main` that have been previously merged into `acceptance`. In some ways this might be better than what you asked for because it would allow you to merge in some stuff from `acceptance` without everything, if say, something on `acceptance` was not wanted for some reason.

Comment: I would agree with @TTT, that seems like a pretty simple github action (run on `main` only, check that the `head` branch is `acceptance`) + required status check on the `main` branch.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same question and got the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70510247/4094939). You will need to set this check at a CICD pipeline on `pull_request` event.