# Lock source branch on Pull Requests

Tags: github, pull-request

I'm defining branch protection rules on GitHub, and I would like to know if is there any way to define a Pull Request flow like: `qa --> main`.

I know it's possible to require pull request before merging (on *Require a pull request before merging* flag under Branches > Branch protection rule), but I didn't find any option for defining this flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way on GitHub to force a source branch to be fixed to a certain value, but you can solve this problem with a required CI check that fails if the PR to `main` has the wrong source branch.  That's the usual way that people handle this sort of issue.

Comment: Thanks @bk2204, I will set up my CICD pipe to perform this check